# Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined error in vuetify treeview

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i got an error like this ."Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined".

my tree data coming from api and im loading it in items

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="search"
  label="Search"
  dark
  solo-inverted
  hide-details
  clearable
  clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
></v-text-field>
<v-checkbox v-model="caseSensitive" dark hide-details label="Case sensitive search"></v-checkbox>
<v-treeview :items="items" :search="search" :open.sync="open" open-on-click>
  <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
    <span>{{ item.display_name }}</span>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    // items: this.entityTreeList,
    rules: {
      required: value => !!value || 'Required.'
    },
    Name: '',
    search: null,
    caseSensitive: false,
    open: [1, 2],
    active: []
  }
},
```

Comment: Is `toLocaleLowerCase` used in your code? Can you inspect the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem using Vuetify 1.5 Treeview.

To solve it I had to add a "name" property to each item in my treeview object.